# Voltage regulator replacement

Tags: voltage-regulator, replacement, lm78xx

I have a gadget (a Sonar) that stopped working (doesn’t respond to power on, power led does not turn on) and opening it to look for the typical signs of failure  I see an L7818 voltage regulator in TO-220 package that looks like it has overheated.

I’m confused about two things: First: Why would one use an 7818 circuit in a board powered by 12V DC? The board has an STM32 microcontroller and peripheral components (wifi etc) so I was expecting to see an L7805, not an 18V one. The 18V could be for powering the analog/sonar bits I suppose, but should I then not *also* find a 5V regulator somewhere for the logic parts? Just out of curiosity, what the likely power supply design here if input power is 12V (boat battery), and the board has a VRM requiring 20+ volts input, and having 18V as output?

Second: the product code on the VRM is a bit charred but looks like “L7818BT”. I can’t find that, but I can find an L7818CV. What is the meaning of the suffix letters in this case?

Edit: top and front view of the board. The VRM that looks overheated is the component screwed to a heat sink on the left in both pictures.

The small stacked pcb wth the large heat sink is related to the WiFi (black wire connects to a case antenna). The two large square components are both arm microcontrollers.

[image][image]

Update: some basic testing confirms the VRM is a red herring, or at least it's not the *only* issue. Applying 12V at the DC input (the 2 pin connection on the left), I can measure 12V at those solder points underneath *only* (see the last image). That is: there is no other place on the board that gets *any* voltage at all. I'd assume that means it has to be one of the very first components being bad then, or a mechanical/connection issue somewhere very near the power connector? Unfortunately the power button connection (the 2 red wires joining the PCB in a pool of yellow goo) hides a lot of the things in the area nearest to the power connection so I'm having a hard time figuring out what's going on right after the power connector.

**Update2/Solution**: The problem was one of the power switch wires (the one connected to the 12V end of the battery) must have come loose from the PCB, under the yellow glue. Instead of trying to repair it which would have required scraping the glue, I tried bypassing the switch and connecting 12V directly to the second power switch wire, which worked. The solution to get a working power switch was to solder a new power switch wire, directly to the +12V connector on the board (posslbly bypassing a component or two such as a diode in the process). Device works perfectly after this, including the switch.

[image]

Comment: `BT` .... bit toasted ..... sorry, could not resist

Comment: Is there a boost converter somewhere? It would be a strange choice perhaps to not just have the boost converter regulate to 18V on its own, but that's the only thing I can imagine you could do to have a 7818 on a 12V board.

Comment: I think if you want to know what that BT means you will have to surf datasheets for L7818s until it shows up on a binning list.  It's a linear regulator, so offhand I can't think of anything they'd need to bin other than packages and temperature ranges.  If you can't find it, I'd suggest making sure the replacement has the widest temperature range you can find.  You wouldn't want to run too too much current off of a linear reg, so I wonder if it's being stepped up by a boost circuit and then regulated for a specific component or a mosfet driver.  Pics would help!

Comment: @felthry, could just be a diode pump, that would explain the regulator.

Comment: @Jasen Ah, good point. Depends on the price point of the device, I think; high-end ones would likely have a boost converter if they need it, and cheap ones might just use a Cockroft-Walton generator.

Comment: This is a cheap device: sub $100. Anything particular that would be interesting to see in pictures? I can se a lot of surface mounted things for the logic, a few capacitors, two large mosfet-like components but the other is obscured. Re: the suffix, I could only find one L7818 which was the “CV” but will double check the specs and compare to 7805BT which seems to be available.

Comment: @AndersForsgren - Although helpful, IMHO the photos are just the start of your work. In your situation, I suggest to reverse-engineer the power input circuitry, to see what happens to the 12V input. Does it go directly to Vin on the 7818? There are also at least 2 other voltage regulators on the board, so investigate their relationship with the 7818 too. Using at least a DMM (perhaps 'scope) measure all voltage rails. "*STM32 microcontroller [...] so I was expecting to see an L7805*" FYI the STM32F103 on that board isn't powered from 5V, so that's no reason to expect to see a 7805. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll start by diagnosing the VRM’s. The only reason I figured its the culprit is because it looks burnt and the device doesn’t seem to get power at all (ie power led does not come on). If the 7818 turns out to  the expected in/out voltages it’s a red herring (it requires more than 20V Vin hence my confusion). I wanted to order the VRM part before I get to the lab where I can do more diagnostics, on the chance that it turbs out to be the fault, hence the guesswork coming before real testing. I’ll update after my diagnosis.

Comment: @AndersForsgren - Thanks. "*it looks burnt*" Photo isn't clear enough for me to confirm that, so while it might be dead, at this stage I'm not assuming that. "*(ie power led does not come on)*" That's new info (please edit question & add it) and would lead immediately to the question of where is the power LED in the photo, and which power rail supplies it? "*7818 [...] requires more than 20V Vin*" Actually 7818 (78xx family) behaviour is more complex than that, but I don't want to waste time explaining without knowing it's relevant i.e. after we know the source of Vin on 7818.

Comment: I did some measurements, and I'm completely stuck. Any last tips for how to measure my way forward from the battery connector to the problem?

Comment: @Anders - Now you've accepted an answer (despite it not solving your problem!) your question is removed from the "unanswered" list (so some people will now ignore it completely) and other readers have less incentive to spend time helping, since they can't gain the extra points for getting the accepted answer. Overall, I suggest that's not the result you wanted :-( This sort of fault-finding is easy with the board in the hands of an experienced engineer, but difficult to talk someone through. Are you prepared to use the site chat, with the board & DMM in front of you to take measurements?

Comment: @SamGibson yes, I realize it wasn’t that clever asking two questions - as a proper answer was given to one part, I’ll accept that and possibly re-ask the diagnostics part as a new question instead (but it will be hard to do given this isn’t the place for “plz help me troubleshoot”-style questions). Will edit as soon as I’m at a proper keyboard. Re: chat+dmm: that’s a good Idea, but I worry there just aren’t any good spots to measure at! I suspect I’ll need to scrape the yellow goo and do some measurements first.

Comment: Update: found a problem: the 2 power leads ending under the yellow goo must be broken. Specifically the one coming (presumably directly) from the battery + side must have been disconnected from the pcb under the glue. If the switch is the "first" component after the battery, that would explain not seeing 12V anywhere but at the battery connector. Bypassing the power switch by shorting the OTHER switch lead to 12V directly, at least now provides the board with power (power led comes on, VRM gets V_in). Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U5 looks like it could be your 5V (or 3.3V) switching IC. 
I'd imagine there's 10V coming from the 7818 into U5 from a 12V input. 
You can look up the data sheet from the MCUs and trace the Vcc pin and see what's powering it. Work backwards to find where the problem might be.

The suffix is usually the input voltage range it can take. Some 78xx can take up to 35V.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my confusion about the serials and the design at least. I'll accept the answer and keep asking the helpful people in the comments for guidance on finding the problem